# How to remove 2nd duplicate from list in python

Tags: python, duplicates

list=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2]

Here I need to remove only the 2nd duplicates (triplicates) and ignore the 1st duplicate.

End result should be as below,

Out_list=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3]

Comment: explain your *2nd duplicate* (your output does have duplicates)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does out_list need to be in the same order as the input?

Comment: Your output doesn't match your request. In both input and output you have 2 occurrences of **3**.

Comment: How are you supposed to deal with quadruplicate for example?

Answer (score 7):

A pythonic way to do it using Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2]
c = Counter()
new_l = [ i for i in l if c.update([i]) or c[i]<3 ] #new_l=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
```

A short explanation: the method `update` of a Counter takes an iterator and increments by one the elements of this iterator and returns `None` which is cast as `False` as a boolean. Hence `c.update([i]) or c[i]<3` is equivalent to `c[i]<3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
In [13]: lst = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2]

In [14]: while True:
    ...:     check_list = [i for i in set(lst) if lst.count(i) > 2]
    ...:     if check_list:
    ...:         for item in check_list:
    ...:             lst.reverse()
    ...:             lst.remove(item)
    ...:             lst.reverse()
    ...:     else:
    ...:         break
    ...:     

In [15]: lst
Out[15]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: not a good solution ...